# Blender 2.8 particles scale is off

Tags: modeling, particles, hair

Particles do not have the same scale as the objects from the collection they're created from:

They're much smaller:

[image]
[image]

The particles were assigned to a plane but appear outside of it as well:

[image]

I've played around with the scale and got them to the original intended size but the buildings were also spaced out outside the plane.

Comment: Try applying scale to the particle objects in the Buildings collection. Then try changing the scale of the particle emitter, on the right side of your screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to scale to 1:1 crashed blender; I managed to solve it by going to the collection, selecting all buildings in edit mode, Ctrl + A then select Scale. Now they are all on the plane:

[image]

Also, Random should be ticked instead of the whole collection, otherwise blender places all elements from the collection in the same position (in my case emission was set to vertex).

Answer (score 2):

Like @stphnl329 says apply the scale of all particle objects, then go to the render settings of your particle system. For some reason the default scale is  0.05, change that to 1
[image]

Comment: Tried it but blender crashed; managed to find a fix through trial and error.